# Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли в данном предложении запятая?

Tags: грамматика

"Она жила в старинном здании 16 века в самом сердце Лондона".

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не соответствует тематике сайта

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Надо написать: "Она жила в старинном здании 16 века, которое располагалось в самом сердце Лондона."

Comment: @Ivan Olshansky Тут не стилистика, а семантика. Лучше явно (лексически) указать, к чему относится  "в самом сердце Лондона", чем выделять эту семантику запятыми. А то будет как у Чехова: "Проезжая вашу станцию и глядя в окно у меня слетела шляпа".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В зависимости от того, к чему относится оборот "*в самом сердце Лондона*". То есть:

1) Если это относится к героине, то есть если мы можем сократить фразу до "*Она жила в самом сердце Лондона*", то запятая нужна:

> "Она жила в старинном здании 16 века, в самом сердце Лондона".

2) Если это относится к дому, то есть кусок "*в старинном здании 16 века*" нельзя выкинуть без потери смысла, то запятая не нужна:

> "Она жила в старинном здании 16 века в самом сердце Лондона".

Comment: Спасибо большое! У меня второй вариант!)))